Reduce all elements from flux before proceeding
I need to make sure all operations on all user items have been completed before doing something with the user record. Does reduce wait for all elements from the flatMap before proceeding? If not, how can I do that?
Flux.fromIterable(userIds)
    // each element has multiple userIds 
    .flatMap(
         userId -> getUserItems(userId)
                                .map(userItemIds -> doSomethingWithUserItemRecord(userId,userItemIds)))
   .reduce(new Result(0, true), this::mergeResult)
   // batch operations on all userIds in an element from the original source 
   .map(result-> doSomethingWithUsersRecords(result))


if you don't need actual results, use then() operation

I do need the result. this is only a section of the pipeline.

then it's collectList()

@IgorArtamonov maybe I wasn't clear enough in the original post, I'm trying to wait for getUserItems and doSomethingWithUserItemRecord to finish for a single batch of userIds. reduce does not wait for all elements?

Sorry, I actually thought you don't want reduce() but use it only to wait for all the elements. If you need to merge as a reduce step, then it works perfectly fine and completes only when all the elements are merged (i.e., waits for all). Same for then() and collectList(). So you can use any of them, including reduce(), depending of what you want to do with the intermediary items

@IgorArtamonov if you add this as an answer, I can accept it.

As per discussion in comments, reduce() processes all the elements before completing. It doesn't wait though, but starts processing the elements as soon as the first one has emitted and produces the output (i.e., completes) when the source has completed (i.e., no more items are expected to come).
If a reducer is just merging all elements into a list, then collectList() do that. In this case it's also possible to wait until all the source items are produced, before processing them on the next step. I.e., you get the final list of items only and only if there were no errors in the source publisher.
If the intermediate results are not needed, and you just want to wait until the input is fully produced without any error, then a simple then() would be better.
All of the mentioned above wait for all the items in the input, before going to the next operation. So it all depends on what you want to do with the original items.

Generally, you don't really know in which order things will be executed, so it might wait, it might not. In order to force the evaluation of a Flux you can insert this:
.collect(Collectors.toList()).flux()

This converts the Flux into a Mono<List>, meaning that it will have to be evaluated, and then converts the Mono back into a Flux.
This does mean that all the values will have to fit into the memory, so be careful about the performance and memory implications.

Does it mean without  .collect  the method can return partial results?
.flatMap(this::doSomething).reduce(this::doSomethingElse).toFuture()
Does this return a future that holds partial results?

does .collect(Collectors.toList()) get all results of a single batch of userIds or all userIds from the original publisher?

What do you mean by partial results? A Flux object?
